# HTML table wont fit whole screen no matter what

Tags: html

Basically, I have a table on my website that wont fit 100% width of the browser screen. Even when I change the width to 110% it simply overlaps the right side but still has a margin space on the left side( the outer space of table). I want the table to be completely pressed against the browser screen from left to right with no space or border at all. how do I do this? I have tried everything and it still wont work. I even tried negative margin and padding

please help I am losing my mind. here is the code I have:

```
<table bgcolor="#DBD9D9" rules="none" border="0" width="110%"cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT HERE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE: I added the css code to the header like colin suggested and it still doesnt work.  body {margin:10px;} table {margin:0 -10px;}

Comment: Set the body's padding and margin to 0. Welcome to SO!

Comment: These attributes are deprecated.

Comment: Have you at all considered that `width="110%"cellspacing="0"` is not a valid attribute? Perhaps you're missing a space somewhere.

Comment: this is what i have currently. does it look wrong ? <table align="left"; width="100%" bgcolor="#DBD9D9" rules="none" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
<td>

Answer (score 0):

DOn't forget to add a `margin: 0;` to the `<body>` tag!

Answer (score 0):

There is a default margin on the body that needs to be removed.

Add the following css to the `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {margin:0;} 
</style>
```

Or

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {margin:10px;}
    table {margin:0 -10px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Is `padding` also a default with the `body` or is it just me? lol

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. how would i do this only for the table and not the whole page. im trying to give the content on the site a two tone look so it seperates every other 500 words or so. also is it possible to do through HTML without touching css? thanks again

Comment: You have to apply some CSS there is no way around it. Since the amount of margin can vary from browser to browser I would recommend setting some kind of default like `body {margin:10px;}` and then set set your tables to have a negative margin `table {margin:0 -10}`. If you dont want all tables to behave this way you could define a class and apply it only to tables you want.

Comment: i added the css code to the header like you suggested and it still doesnt work.  <style type="text/css">
    body {margin:10px;}
    table {margin:0 -10px;}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

I had this once too: the solution was to set the body's margin and padding to 0. (Perhaps width to 100% helps too.)

Comment: i already did that and it didnt working. i do thing colen is onto something. any examples of how you would re work the HTML code above?

Comment: <table bgcolor="#DBD9D9" rules="none" border="0" width="110%"cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>TEXT HERE</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: @user1993107 Colin's answer is exactly the same as mine. I meant the CSS properties, the body tag doesn't have such attributes.

Comment: @user1993107 Do you know what CSS _is_?

Comment: i've never messed with it im a newbie. i tried all the sugested solutions still not working. there is space still inbetween the table and browser width. <table align="center"; width="100%" bgcolor="#DBD9D9" rules="none" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
<td>

Comment: You have to add the code of Colin's answer to the `head` tag of your page. @user1993107 if that doesn't work try adding `padding: 0;` between the curly braces (`{` and `}`).